# SiteCore CMS - Webpage Becomes Unresponsive at every click

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am a new user of SiteCore platform and facing "Page Unresponsive" Issue - extremely frequently - on SiteCore CMS. This happens on Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox. This happens at every 30-40 seconds.

Could anyone please share insights on what might have gone wrong and what steps to take to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the bad performance could be generated by different problems. I would recommend you check your console for errors or monitor Sitecore ajax calls that result in errors or are very slow/unresponsive.

[chrome web developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f9aA.png)

Also you can check Sitecore logs for errors. These are located in [data-folder]/logs in log.[date].txt file

You can also check if you met the requirements for installing Sitecore 8:

- IIS 8.5 or IIS 8.0
- .Net framework 4.5 and above,
- Miminum MS Sql server 2008 R2 SP1 or above editions like SQL server 2012, SQL server 2014
- MongoDB Database 2.6x if you have Analytics enabled

Comment: Hi @alinaistfodor many thanks for the suggestions. I passed these suggestion to the developers; they also did some other research and finally now it is working well. Now there are 2 out of 10 chances of page becomes unresponsive. (previously it was 10/10 lol)